# What is "tagged memory"?

Tags: memory

What is "tagged memory" and how does it help in reducing program size?

Comment: Only thing that comes up on google for tagged memory at the moment is this stackoverflow page :)  Maybe you'll need to clarify in order to tell us what was the context in which you heard it.

Comment: If this is homework, you could add some information about the context in which you saw this term. Might help to get an answer.

Answer (score 4):

You may be referring to a [tagged union](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tagged_union), or more specifically a hardware implementation like the tagged architecture used in LISP machines. Basically a method for storing data with type information.

In a LISP machine, this was done in-memory by using a longer word length and using some of the extra bits to store type information. Handling and checking of tags was done implicitly in hardware.

For a type-safe C++ implementation, see boost:variant.

Comment: There is also a wiki page about tagged memory in hardware here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tagged_architecture

Answer (score 1):

Not sure, but it is possible that you are referring to [garbage collection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_collection_%28computer_science%29), which is the process of automatically disposing of no longer used objects created when running a program.

"Tagged memory" can be a synonym for [mark-and-sweep](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_collection_%28computer_science%29#Naive_mark-and-sweep), which is the most basic way to implement garbage collection.

If this is all wrong, please edit your question to clarify.

Answer (score 1):

The Windows DDK makes use of "pool tags" when allocating memory out of the kernel page pool. It costs 4 bytes of memory per allocation, but allows you to label (i.e. tag) portions of kernel memory which might help with debugging and detecting memory leaks.

BTW I don't see how anything called "tagged memory" could reduce program code size. It sounds like extra work, which translates to "more code" and "bigger program." Maybe it's meant to reduce the memory footprint somehow?

Answer (score 0):

[Here's](http://basen.oru.se/kurser/koi/2008-2009-p1/texter/gc/index.html) a more technical description going into the implementation details as to how this is used for garbage collection. You may also want to check out the wikipedia article about [Tagged Pointers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tagged_pointer).